# Prove that if $f$ is derivable in $(a,b)$ and $f'$ is increasing, then $f$ is convex

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

A function $f: [a,b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is convex if for all $x_1,x_2 \in [a,b]$ with $x_1<x_2$ we have that

$\displaystyle\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2 -x_1} > \displaystyle\frac{f(x)-f(x_1)}{x -x_1}, \;\;\;\; \forall\;x\in[x_1,x_2]$.

B) Prove that if $f$ is derivable in $(a,b)$ and $f'$ is increasing, then $f$ is convex (in particular, if exists $f''$ and it is strictly positive, $f$ is convex).

Thank you very much.

Comment: What if $x=x_2$?

Answer (score 0):

Simple algebra shows that the inequality in the definition is also equivalent to the following:  $\frac {f(x_2)-f(x)} {x_2-x} \geq \frac {f(x)-f(x_1)} {x-x_1}$ for  $x_1 <x <x_2$.

This new inequality is immediate from MVT. Just apply MVT to each side of the inequality.

Comment: But, what do you mean by applying MVT to each side of the inequality? Because if I do that, the expression will change to something similar to: $f'(c_1) >= f'(c_2)$, for $c_1 \in [x,x_2]$, $c_2 \in [x_1,x]$

Comment: @galgarabel $c_1 >x>c_2$ and $f'$ is increasing, so $f'(c_1) \geq f'(c_2)$. Isn 't that what yo have to prove?